# Xcode Gives Strange Output From NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When I run this code, the output is some 1084848 to the console. I can't figure out why such odd output... here is the code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
 {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   int someNumber = 3; 
   [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someNumber]]; 
   NSLog(@"%i" , [array objectAtIndex:0]);
   [pool drain];
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the pseudocode of your program:

```
//
//  Inside of your main function....
//
//  Set up the Autorelease pool and then create an array
//
//  Declare an int  
//
//  Add the int to an array, while wrapping it in an NSNumber
//
//  Log the value of the first object in the array, using the int formatter
//
// Clean up and return
//
```

You are logging the first object in the array, but `NSArray` cannot hold a primitive that's not wrapped in an Objective-C object.

To better understand your code, try changing these lines of code:

```
int someNumber = 3; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someNumber]];
```

Expand them a little. Try this:

```
int someNumber = 3; 
NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:someNumber];
[array addObject:aNumber];
```

So, you've correctly wrapped the `int` in an `NSNumber`, but you're not unwrapping it.  You need to ask your `NSNumber` for the `int` that it holds like so:

```
[[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Or, to do the logging in one line:

```
NSLog(@"%i" , [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue]);
```

The characters "`%i`" is called a "formatter". Different kinds of values require different formatters. When you are using an Objective-C object, you use "`%@`". For an `NSInteger` or `int`, you'd use `%i`. For a float, you'd use "`%f`". The point is that you need to either unwrap that number, or use the Objective-C formatter for strings.

A quick note about that weird value you were getting earlier: That's a memory address in RAM. It's the closest thing you're going to get when you use an incorrect formatter. In some cases, using the wrong formatter will cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. You were "lucky" and got a weird value instead of a dead program. I suggest learning about strings and formatters before you move on. It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

the "%i" format specifier expects an integer, not an Object.

Try `NSLog(@"%i" , [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue]);`

XCode is probably giving you a warning on this line: something like "Conversion specifies type 'int', but argument has type 'id'".

Comment: Wait... but the objectAtIndex 0 of array is an integer, which is a primitive, not an object. Right?

Comment: @Monkeyanator objectAtIndex: 0 is an object, an NSNumber.

Comment: @Monkeyanator: only objects can be stored in arrays (hence the method names `addObject:` and `objectAtIndex:`), so your `objectAtIndex:` call returns an `NSNumber` object. To get the "raw" primitive value, you need to call `NSNumber`'s `-intValue` method.

Comment: NSArrays can only contain objects, not primitive types. The result of `-objectAtIndex:0` is the `NSNumber` object you created on the previous line. `[NSNumber numberWithInt:someNumber]` creates an `NSNumber` object from the primitive integer `someNumber`.

Comment: ahh okay thank you that helps a lot. I'll be sure to check your comment as soon as I can (in 50 seconds)

Comment: @Monkeyanator - I've put together a thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%i` for integer values then you should give arguments as integer as below

```
NSLog(@"%i" , [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue]);
```

But when you want object to be displayed then you must use `%@` which identifies object in general case as below:

```
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```